# JxBrowser: Failed to send message. Channel is already closed

Tags: java, jxbrowser

Sometimes I got this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to send message. Channel is already closed.
```

As I know, this exception occurs when the browser is disposed (But I did not manually dispose it)

Is there any method to "restart" or "un-dispose" or "re-init" the browser?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't dispose `Browser` instance and see this exception, then it indicates that something goes wrong in Chromium engine that leads to unexpected channel disconnection. You can try re-creating `Browser` instance by creating another one. The already disposed `Browser` instance cannot be re-created/restored. I recommend that the root cause that leads to channel disconnection is fixed.

Comment: what do you mean "I recommend that the root cause that leads to channel disconnection is fixed"? "is fixed" by chrome engine or by new version of jxbrowser?

Comment: I mean that first we need to find out root cause of the issue and fix it. The exception you see isn't a root cause. To find out the root cause I need to reproduce this issue somehow. Could you please provide me with steps to reproduce this exception and description of the environment where the issue happens?

Comment: I know this is not the place to report bug, but the getBoundingClientRect always return y with the same value x. I have to use javascript to get instead

Comment: @yelliver thank you for letting me know about this issue. I reproduced it. It will be fixed in next update.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to inform you that we've fixed the mentioned issue

A new **version 6.14.1 of JxBrowser** with improved Chromium binaries extraction logic and quite a number of requested fixes is available for download from our web-site www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser